# Error: Unsupported attribute when adding outputs

Tags: azure, terraform

The following code successfully deploys 2 x log analytic workspaces in different regions in azure in their own region based resource groups.

**locals.tf**

```
locals {
  resource_groups = {
    for k, v in var.workspaces : k => {
      location = v.location
    }
  }
}
```

**main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "workspaces" {
  for_each = local.resource_groups

  name     = each.key
  location = each.value.location
}

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "workspaces" {
  for_each = var.workspaces

  name                = each.key
  location            = each.value.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.workspaces[each.key].name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = each.value.retention_in_days
}
```

**variables.tf**

```
variable "workspaces" {
  type = map(object({
    location          = string
    retention_in_days = number
  }))
  default = {
    workspace1 = {
      location          = "australiasoutheast"
      retention_in_days = 30
    }
    workspace2 = {
      location          = "australiaeast"
      retention_in_days = 30
    }
    # Add more workspaces as needed
  }
}
```

**outputs.tf**

```
# Define outputs
output "workspace_ids" {
  value = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.workspaces[*].id
}

output "workspace_names" {
  value = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.workspaces[*].name
}

output "resource_group_ids" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.workspaces[*].id
}

output "resource_group_names" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.workspaces[*].name
}

output "resource_group_locations" {
  value = azurerm_resource_group.workspaces[*].location
}
```

When adding outputs I am receiving the following error and im not sure why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `for_each`, you have to use `values`. For example:

```
output "workspace_ids" {
  value = values(azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.workspaces)[*].id
}
```